# Branch cuts for $\sqrt{z(z-1)}$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, branch-cuts, branch-points

I am studying for quals and found this question in a previous exam:

> Find a branch cut for $\sqrt{z(z-1)}$ that is analytic in $\mathbb{C}
> \> \setminus [0, 1]$ and takes the value of $-\sqrt{2}$ at $z=2$.

My first instinct was to rewrite this as $z \sqrt{1-\frac{1}{z}}$. The value requirement suggests that $\arg_\tau(1/2) = 2 \pi + 2 \pi k$. But this is analytic on $z \in \mathbb{C} \setminus \mathbb{R}$, which isn't what we want.

After that, I did some googling and found that some people choose to rewrite powers of this form as $f(z) = \sqrt{|z||z-1|} e^{i \frac12 (\arg(z) + arg(z-1))}$ to find their branch points. But I don't know how to proceed further with this to get the branch cut I want.

Comment: How about $$ f(z)=-z\left(1-\frac{1}{z}\right)^{1/2}, $$ where $w^{1/2}=\exp(\frac{1}{2}\log w)$ stands for the principal square root? This $f(z)$ is analytic away from the branch cut $\{0\}\cup\{z:1-\frac{1}{z}\leq 0\}=[0,1]$ and satisfies $$f(z)^2=z^2\left(1-\frac{1}{z}\right)=z(z-1)$$ together with $f(2)=-\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: Indeed, that works. Thank you! I got into the habit of always writing $z = \sqrt{z^2}$ without considering the other branch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the definition of the complex exponential, we have

$\sqrt{z(z-1)}=e^{\frac12\log(z(z-1))}$

In term of set equivalence, $\log(z(z-1))=\log(z)+\log(z-1)$.  This means that any value of $\log(z(z-1))$ can be expressed as some value of $\log(z)$ and some value of $\log(z-1)$.  Conversely, it means that the some of any value of $\log(z)$ and any value of $\log(z-1)$ can be expressed as some value of $\log(z(z-1))$.  Therefore, we can write (as set equivalence)

$$\sqrt{z(z-1)}=\sqrt{z}\sqrt{z-1}$$

There are branch points at $z=0$ and $z=1$ (and one at the point at infinity).  We are free to choose branch cuts that begin at these branch points and extend to the point at infinity.

Let's choose branch cuts from $z=0$ and $z=1$ that are rays along the negative real axis such that

$$-\pi\le\arg(z)<\pi\\$$
$$\pi\le\arg(z-1)<3\pi$$

At $z=2$, $\sqrt{z}=\sqrt{2}$ and $\sqrt{z-1}=-1$ so that $\sqrt{z(z-1)}$

We could have chosen instead the branches in which

$$\pi\le\arg(z)<3\pi\\$$
$$-\pi\le\arg(z-1)<\pi$$

Then, we see that at $z=2$, we have $\sqrt{z}=-\sqrt{2}$ and $\sqrt{z-1}=1$ so that $\sqrt{z(z-1)}=-\sqrt{2}$ as expected!